# WebGL detected as supported when it is actually not

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, webgl, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using WebGL from a WebView in Android. For detecting whether WebGL is supported or not, I am using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953053/1816603).

Android KitKat devices do not have WebGL support enabled, as mentioned everywhere. However, in my 4.4.2 test device, the detection function is returning true, and when invoking http://webglreport.com from a WebView it also says WebGL1 is supported.

Unsurprisingly, nothing gets rendered. So I would like to avoid using the WebGL version of the page if WebGL is not going to work.

Is there any way I could detect better for webGL? Or should I just say "if Android < 5, don't even try to check whether WebGL is supported, as it may lie".

Comment: Which device appears to misreport?

Comment: In this case it is a Jiayu S2 phone.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar experiences with Android devices. Solved by blacklisting Android browser (and, if I understand correctly, stock web view as well). Updated Chrome usually works fine.

Comment: Thanks. I can't really blacklist the WebView, since the goal is for a hybrid app using WebView.

Comment: There may be another way. Try to render small simple scene and read it back from a framebuffer. If it's appear fine, then the application can continue to use a WebGL code path. Otherwise, show an error message of use a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

In line with @kirill-dmitrenko's answer, but avoiding parsing User Agents, I have blacklisted all browsers that do not support the "let" construct (http://caniuse.com/#feat=let), which though unrelated, seems to be supported by all modern browsers supporting webgl:

```
var supported;

try {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    supported = !! window.WebGLRenderingContext && (canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl'));
} catch(e) { supported = false; }

try {
    // let is by no means required, but will help us rule out some old browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=let
    eval('let foo = 123;');
} catch (e) { supported = false; }

if (supported === false) {
    console.log("WebGL is not supported");
}
```