# Django views detect if client uses webgl compatible browser

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, webgl

Is there any option to detect in the view function if the browser from which the user is coming is webGL compatible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Detecting WebGL is a matter of using JavaScript on the frontend (see [Proper way to detect WebGL support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871077/proper-way-to-detect-webgl-support)), so I don't think there is a way to do this directly in the backend in a Django view.

What you could do is perform the detection with JavaScript on the first page the user visits and use AJAX to store the result in a server-side variable which you can use in subsequent requests to decide whether to use WebGL features or not.

Comment: Is there a way that this information is given through the request? Same as the requests gives GET, POST, COOKIES, etc.. so it also gives WEBGLCOMPATIBLE or similar called variable

Comment: @Ignasi not that I know of.

Comment: Thank you very much @voodoo-burger!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on voodoo's answer, here is the javascript to quickly determine wheter a client has webgl support

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var names = ["webgl", "experimental-webgl", "webkit-3d", "mozwebgl"];
    var webgl_supported = false;

    for(var i in names) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext(names[i], { });

            if (gl && typeof gl.getParameter == "function") {
                webgl_supported = true;
                break;
            }
        } catch(e) { }
    }

   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "/webgl_enabled_handler");
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
   xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({webgl_enabled: webgl_supported }));
```

This assumes that in your html page/template there's a canvas element with id "canvas".

The resulting json would be sent as a POST request to django after page loads

Unfortunately I doubt there's a way to determine webgl support through a general GET request from django

Comment: FYI: "webkil-3d" and "mozwebgl" are not needed. They were a thing for a few months in like 2010 and are long gone. Similarly "experimental-webgl" is only used by Edge at this point because it's WebGL implementation is still not spec compliant.