# How to catch "You need a browser which supports WebGL to run this content." error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a WebGL browser game that does not work for users that have the "Use hardware acceleration when available" setting unchecked in Chrome, they get a message that says "You need a browser which supports WebGL to run this content, please try using Firefox". I would like to catch this error, and display a custom message/send them to my guide page which shows them how to enable hardware acceleration in Chrome, so they don't get turned off and leave all together. How would I be able to do this?

[image: error]

Comment: there is no error to catch

Comment: @JaromandaX well, I would like to catch the popup so I can display my own custom version

Comment: May be relevant.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871077/proper-way-to-detect-webgl-support

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code would work for you:

```
var hasWebGL = (function() {
  if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext) {
    return 0;
  }

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

  if (!gl) {
    gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    if (!gl) return 0;
  }

  return 1;
})();

if (!hasWebGL) alert('Custom message!');
```

But you might want to check [the full script](http://www.svgsch.at/Veggen3D_WGL/Compressed/UnityConfig.jsgz) I found over there that checks webgl compatibility.

Hope it help you.