# How to determine whether a website use WebGL1.0/2.0?

Tags: javascript, testing, webgl, analysis

I am developing a chrome extension that could inform the user of the WebGL usage in the current tab. This helps me to **estimate the usage of WebGL on modern websites** nowadays.

(I think a trivial approach to this question is to check whether a `<canvas>` tag is used. But things are getting complicated regarding machine learning (ML) scenarios. Web ML frameworks utilize WebGL with a custom GLSL to accelerate computing. Maybe some static/dynamic analysis of the JavaScript file is needed?)

Comment: Maybe  this question [proper-way-to-detect-webgl-suppor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871077/proper-way-to-detect-webgl-support) will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! @bbbbbbbboat
 Sorry for my poor English misleading you. What this extension wants to know is whether the current tab is **using** a WebGL context for rendering rather than could support WebGL context. ;)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your question!
I think the approach you mentioned is quite hard and may not work, because using WebGL even doesn't require a real canvas on dom. 
Or maybe there is some state variable in WebGL  context to describe the current working state? I don't know for sure, and hope may help you a little.

Comment: Appreciate your help @bbbbbbbboat! I found a [website](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) that visually presents the global states of WebGL. Maybe a monitor of the global state or some software analysis techniques is needed! Thanks!