# get cpu / gpu capabilities from client in react / typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, browser

is it somehow possible to get the hardware specs (at least openGL / webGL) capabilities from a client in a react/typescript Application? Is there any kind of standarized browser api of some sort? i can only find useragents/language and plattform like so:

```
  <p>User Agent: {navigator.userAgent}</p>
  <p>Platform: {navigator.platform}</p>
  <p>Online: {navigator.onLine ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</p>
  <p>Language: {navigator.language}</p>
```

but since i have integrated some babylonjs 3d stuff, i need to know if the client can handle it.

cheers and thanks!!

Comment: For detecting webGL capability check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953053/6212530

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not really much you can get from Browser api. However you can get information about memory and javascript via `window.performance.memory`. Another thing is, you can see some information from performance monitor in dev tools.

[image: Performance monitor]

Also you might be interested in investigating the GPUBuffer, but it's experimental yet, so use with caution https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GPUBuffer